# Can't assign to function call (python 3)

Tags: python

```
print ("**     **     ***")
print ("**     **     ***")
print ("*********     ***")
print ("**     **     ***")
print ("**     **     ***")
Contacts = [0]
if Contacts == [0]:
    print ("You have no friends!")
    from time import sleep
Contact = input("Would you like to add a contact: Y or N?")
if Contact == "Y":
    for c in range(0,1):
        print (1 - c)
        sleep(1)
    Contact = input("Name:")
    Contacts.append(Contact)
    Contact1 = input ("age:")
    Contacts.append(Contact1)
    Contact2 = input ("Location:")
    Contacts.append(Contact2)
    Contact3 = input ("Phone Number:")
    Contacts.append(Contact3)
    Contactsn = open("Contactsn.txt", "w")
    Contactsn.write(Contact)
    Contactsn.write(Contact1)
    Contactsn.write(Contact2)
    Contactsn.write(Contact3)
    print (Contact)
    print (Contact1)
    print (Contact2)
    print (Contact3)
    Contactsn.close()

    Contact = input("Would you like to see your Contacts:Y or N?")
    if Contact == "Y":
        Contactsn()
    else:
     Contact = input("Would you like to see your Contacts:Y or N?")
    if Contact == "Y":    
       Contactsn()

    def Contactsn():
                 Contactsn() = open("Contactsn.txt", "r")
                 print (Contactsn.read())
    quit
```

when I run this it says cant assign function, how can I fix this?

Comment: `Contactsn` **`()`** `= open("Contactsn.txt", "r")` (and it's not ideal to shadow the function's name, in general)...

Answer (score 2):

This block is the problem

```
def Contactsn():
    Contactsn() = open("Contactsn.txt", "r")
    print (Contactsn.read())
```

You are trying to assign the result of `open` to the result of calling your function `contactsn()`? Either the `()` is a typo, and you're about to shadow your function name with a variable with the same name, or you are trying some really odd recursive strangeness.

Comment: So should I change the function name??

Comment: That would be a start, and also I'm assuming this line should read `Contactsn = open("Contactsn.txt", "r")`

Comment: So I changed function name and variable name aswell

Comment: def contactsn():
    contactsn() = open("Coontactsn.txt", "r")
    print (Contactsn.read())
    quit

Comment: Thanks!! I got rid of the ()